# Restoring backup on sql server hosted on linux VM

Tags: sql-server, linux, sql-server-2016

I am trying to restore a database backup on SQL server hosted on linux VM. Backup files are placed on a windows file system network path. I mounted that path in linux /home/user/WinMap/

Now when I am trying to restore database backup using restore screen, I see the path like

> C:\var\opt\mssql\data

. I can no where see my mounted path that is

> /home/user/WinMap/

so that I can restore my backups.

Any idea how can I handle linux file system in SQL server would be highly appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Does the SQL user on Linux have access to the path?

Comment: I do not understand Linux too well so may need to do research on this. User who installed SQL server is having access to path definitely have access.

Comment: You would need to make sure the SQL user has access to the share. When you mount the share you need to either give permissions to mssql user or MSSQL group (then have a SQL user part of the group). Here is a good article talking about Linux permissions: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-linux-permissions

Answer (score 2):

Not using SSMS.. and using references from here:[Restore a SQL Server database from Windows to Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-migrate-restore-database)

Next step,once you placed backup file in linux is to move the backup file to  `/var/opt/mssql`

This can be done using

Move the backup file
At this point, the backup file is on your Linux server. Before restoring the database to SQL Server, you must place the backup in a subdirectory of /var/opt/mssql.

> Open a Terminal on the target Linux machine that contains the backup.
>
> Enter super user mode.

sudo su

> Create a new backup directory. The -p parameter does nothing if the directory already exists.

```
mkdir -p /var/opt/mssql/backup
```

> Move the backup file to that directory. In the following example, the backup file resides in the home directory of user1. Change the command to match the location of AdventureWorks2014.bak on your machine.

```
mv /home/user1/AdventureWorks2014.bak /var/opt/mssql/backup/
```

> Exit super user mode.

```
exit
```

Now to restore ,you have to use SQLCMD..

> In the same terminal, launch sqlcmd. The following example connects to the local SQL Server instance with the SA user. Enter the password when prompted or specify the password with the -P parameter.

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA
```

> After connecting, enter the following RESTORE DATABSE command, pressing ENTER after each line. The example below restores the AdventureWorks2014.bak file from the `/var/opt/mssql/backup directory`.

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks
FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/AdventureWorks2014.bak'
WITH MOVE 'AdventureWorks2014_Data' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/AdventureWorks2014_Data.mdf',
MOVE 'AdventureWorks2014_Log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/AdventureWorks2014_Log.ldf'
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! My requirement is to restore backups from a network location. Basically we have huge backups stored on a centralized network location. Copying them on VM would cost us precious disk space.

Comment: I followed your stept but I still get the same error. My database is stored at `/var/opt/mssql/backup/` Any ideas?
`Cannot open backup device '/var/opt/mssql/backup/MyDB.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).`

Comment: use sudo,it says access denied,not ,file not found